# label not clearint in uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uilabel

i just add two uilables to table view cell add names and numbers to that lables when i reload the data in table view that meal whether i add or delete a contact from the table view the data in the lables are ovelaping that mean not reloading the lables ... untill the view is reload .....

can any any one please help me how to overcome this....

Comment: Could you post some code to clarify the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some kind of code will definitely help to solve ur problem.Just try to paste ur cellForrowAtIndexPath method to make it clear what r u doing with Code?

One more thing the Overlapping & reloading are different things.You can't reload the Label but try to reload the table using

[yourTableObject reloadData];

in the methods where you do add or delete or where your array for table gets update.